# Why Cygwin port of 64 bit clang cannot find the standard lib, but 32 bit port can

Tags: cygwin, clang

A simple program like

```
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v(10);
}
```

would report the "fatal error 'vector' file not found" error. But the 32 bit port compiles fine. Reinstallation of the 64 bit package doesn't solve the problem. Should I modify some PATH?

Thanks!

Comment: This has happened to me as well.  Alas, I haven't gotten around to figuring out why.  The Clang folks do not include the C++ standard libraries in the Windows binary; my guess is that you have to do a full build of Clang yourself, including the standard libraries.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What I don't quite understand yet is why the 32 bit port works fine, though the runtime performance isn't on par. I'm almost sure I did something wrong, as otherwise why the port exists.

Comment: Windows support is an afterthought.